# How to convert the LayerDrawable to Drawable in Android?

Tags: bitmap, drawable

In my app i use the **LayerDrawable** to display overlayer image.and i do this is successfully use of layerDrawable.

after i get layerDrawable set as a imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);

Now i want to use this image drawable take as Bitmap and use in next imageprocessing.
but when i try to get the Bitmap use of this

```
((BitmapDrawable)imageLayout.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

i got the following Error.

```
04-04 12:56:02.102: E/AndroidRuntime(15127): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

so i change the follow of my image processing and try to convert the **LayerDrawable** to **Drawable** and set this drawable as imageLayout backGround.
then it's work perfectly.
**My problem is how to convert the LayerDrawable to drwable?**

please any one help.
give me some idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a test, I haven't tried this

```
public Drawable geSingleDrawable(LayerDrawable layerDrawable){

          int resourceBitmapHeight = 136, resourceBitmapWidth = 153;

          float widthInInches = 0.9f;

          int widthInPixels = (int)(widthInInches * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
          int heightInPixels = (int)(widthInPixels * resourceBitmapHeight / resourceBitmapWidth);

          int insetLeft = 10, insetTop = 10, insetRight = 10, insetBottom = 10;

          layerDrawable.setLayerInset(1, insetLeft, insetTop, insetRight, insetBottom);     

          Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthInPixels, heightInPixels, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
          layerDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels);
          layerDrawable.draw(canvas);

          BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
          bitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, widthInPixels, heightInPixels);

          return bitmapDrawable;
}
```

Comment: @Lester If you find this answer is not working for your case,So to get solution for you please briefly explain your case and code OR best way is to start your own Question.! Giving Negative vote won't let me know anything about your case/issue.