# Seekbar's thumb animation while dragging

Tags: android, seekbar

I am creating a seekbar with custom thumb. So my thumb it layeredDrawable. So I want to resize my thumb image while dragging thumb.

I mean when I will drag my thumb... thumb size will increase and seekbar position should not be change.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: so basically you have an image and you want to re-size it while moving the seekbar??

Comment: yes @Tasos i am looking for that :)

Comment: @Newts is my answer helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the seek bars thumb size as you slide requires some code

```
android:thumb="@drawable/round"
```

**Code**

```
private SeekBar seekBar;
```

in `OnCreate` add

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBarID);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            int progress = 0;

            @Override

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {

                progress = progresValue;

                Resources res = getResources();
                Drawable thumb = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.round);
                int h = progress / 10;
                int w = h;
                Bitmap bmpOrg = ((BitmapDrawable) thumb).getBitmap();
                Bitmap bmpScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpOrg, w, h, true);
                Drawable newThumb = new BitmapDrawable(res, bmpScaled);
                newThumb.setBounds(0, 0, newThumb.getIntrinsicWidth(), newThumb.getIntrinsicHeight());
                seekBar.setThumb(newThumb);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

**Tested** and works as expected. ie as you move the thumb it gets smaller to the left and larger to the right

This line here `int  h = progress / 10`;` is what calculates the new thumb size as you slide so you will need to play around with some math to get the exact result you require

Comment: @Newts  --  you could convert it to bitmap  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805060/how-to-convert-the-layerdrawable-to-drawable-in-android

Comment: I converted... but it become very small and some time its not correct also. Some time seek bar is invisible.

Comment: @Newts  -- as i mentioned in my Answer-- this (int h = progress / 10) is what calculates the math for the new size so you need your own math to get it right. Example. if the max of the seek bar is 100 so the scale is (0 to 100) and the original drawable  size is 40px x 40px then you need to calculate eg if progress is @ 50 then the calculation will be (40 / (100 / progress)) = 20px -- i guess when the seekbar is @ 1 then the drawable would be invisible as you say so what you can do is multiply my above equation by 1.5

Comment: But what about seekbar repositioning. Seekbae change its position when thumb size get changed.

Comment: @Newts  -- thats probably becasue you have   android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the seekbar so while the thumb gets smaller or bigger the seekbar appears to be moving due to the seekbars total height. What you can try is wrapping the seekbar inside a frame layout with a specific layout height and keep the seek bar always centered so it wont move using (android:layout_centerInParent="true")

Comment: Thanks you so much... you helped me alot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use selector for seekbar thumb like this one

**thumb.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_small" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_big" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_small" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_small"/>
</selector>
```

and reference this in your seekbar like this **your layout file.xml**

```
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarRadius"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="100"
            android:maxHeight="10dp"
            android:minHeight="10dp"
            android:progress="100"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />
```

**thumb_big.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FF049BFF" />
        <size
            android:width="40dp"
            android:height="40dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**thumb_small.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FF049BFF" />
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: @Newts (dragging state  = when your thumb state is pressed) which i have included in selector I think you gotta give it try

Comment: its increasing seekbar size while dragging :(

Comment: @Newts so is it right or you need something else i am still confused what you wanna do

Comment: I want to change thumb size seekbar size always be same, but its not in that way

Comment: @Newts i Think you are confused by names i have edited those and you can clearly see that the bar is having fixed size that you needed and thumb size are increasing decreasing as different drawbles for different states and i am only setting thumb in seekbar which you want